# Find orthogonal basis of a space

Tags: vector-spaces, hamel-basis

I am trying to find an orthogonal basis of a space W defined by vectors. $ W=[(0,1,0,1),(1,1,0,1),(0,0,0,1)] $ . How would I achieve so? I have no idea how to begin. In my textbook there is a hing to find such vectors, so that they are mutually perpendicular, but that doesn't help me much. Thanks!

Comment: Gram-schmidt process?

Comment: @ChrisCuster Could you explain further?

Comment: Is there any particular requirement with respect to the method to be used? This example can be solved very easily by examining your vectors.

Comment: @broncoAbierto No, there is no required method.

Comment: Then think of the vectors of the canonical basis, and see if you can get anything from there.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see.  Gram-schmidt may not be necessary.

The space is at most $3$ dimensional.   And one easily gets $(1,0,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0,0)$ in addition to $(0,0,0,1)$ in the span.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the [Gramm-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to your set of vectors, then you will get$$\left\{\frac1{\sqrt2}(0,1,0,1),(1,0,0,0),\frac1{\sqrt2}(0,-1,0,1)\right\}.$$This is an orthogonal (orthonormal actually) of your space $W$.